# Change password for farm account on SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

I got a message, my farm account will be expired after 7 days, is there anything that we need to do on SharePoint if the password is expired?

Comment: Where did you receive this message? Central admin? If so, do you have the full message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if any service applications use the farm account, then update the identify of them.

A blog for your reference(should work for SharePoint 2019):
https://www.trustsharepoint.com/2015/06/step-by-step-changing-sharepoint-2013.html